# ElasticSearch Error: QueryParsingException[[mongoindex] failed to find geo_point field [pin.location]];

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am newbie to ES. I was trying to write java program to do geosearch using ES against MongoDB(installed river plugin etc and able to get the normal search using java program). 
I have a collection (table) in mongodb which has latitide and longitude values stored.Now I want to retreive the records based on lat and long which I am passing from Java program.

```
    FilterBuilder filter =  FilterBuilders.geoDistanceFilter("pin.location").lat(10).lon(20).distance(5,DistanceUnit.KILOMETERS).geoDistance(GeoDistance.PLANE);

    SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(INDEX)
                                    .setTypes(TYPE)
                                    .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
                                    .setQuery(matchAllQuery())
                                    .setPostFilter(filter)
                                    .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true)
                                    .execute()
                                    .actionGet();
```

If I execute the above program, I am getting  " QueryParsingException[[mongoindex] failed to find geo_point field [pin.location]];" 
what is this pin.location? Also my mongodb table has columns 'Latitude" and 'Longitude'. But in the above filter I have 'lat(10).lon(20)'. I am missing something here.
Please help me to understand.  Any quick help highly appreciated.

Full stack tarce:

},"explain":true}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[mongoindex] failed to find geo_point field [pin.location]]; }
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.onFirstPhaseResult(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:233)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$1.onFailure(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:179)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$12.handleException(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:351)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleException(MessageChannelHandler.java:185)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:175)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:125)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Thanks,
Sri

Comment: Before you start writing Java code, can you create an HTTP request that makes the same query to ES ? something like: `http://url-to-es/index/document?query=...`

Answer (score 1):

The filter you are creating is based on the field pin.location

```
FilterBuilders.geoDistanceFilter("pin.location")
```

That answers your question about that this pin.location is. Start looking at the mapping of your index to see if the field you are adding to elasticsearch is of type **geo_point**. I haven't used the mongo river myself, but according to this issue you have to provide your own mapping.

https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/issues/218#issuecomment-35824681

Below an example coming from the mentioned post above:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/location_test' -d '
{
    "mappings": {
        "places": {
            "properties": {
               "location": {
                    "type": "geo_point"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

More information about geo_point in elasticsearch can be found here:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-point-type.html

Comment: Not sure what you mean, what have you done? Maybe it is wise to try to come up with a curl query first that you are executing and the expected response. That makes it a lot easier to talk about it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the information. Issue is resolved. Worked fine with the following configuration.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/myindex' -d '
{
   "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 2,
        "number_of_replicas" : 1
    },
   "mappings" : {
      "my_details" : {
          "properties" : {
              "my_id" : {"type" : "integer", "store" : "yes" , "index":"not_analyzed"},
              "location" : {"type" : "geo_point", "store" : "yes", "index":"not_analyzed"}
          }
      }
  }

}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/my_river/_meta' -d '
{
    "type": "mongodb",
    "mongodb": {
        "db": "MyDatabase",
        "collection": "my_details"
    },
    "index": {
        "name": "myindex",
        "type": "my_details"
    }

}'
```

Note: MongoDb has 'my_details' collection in 'MyDatabase'.
Cheers,
Cdhar